# Unexpected tomcat memroy usage increasing monitored by jconsole

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, jvm, jconsole

I am learning jvm and I try to analyse memory used in tomcat. When tomcat started, Eden usage is shown as follows:
[Tomcat eden space usage monitored by jconsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5IT5.jpg)

No war was deployed in tomcat, and every default contexts such as hostmanager, manager were removed. Tomcat was started by default configuration and no request was accepted. It was same in debug mode and no debug mode. When GC is running, the memory usage was decreased. **What caused memory usage increasing?** Could any one help me? Thank you.
Runtime environment:
jdk1.8.0_112
apache-tomcat-8.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is in regards to the memory utilization fluctuation you see through JConsole. I will try to provide my two cents in here...

Keep in mind that even though there may be no WAR file deployed, there is still a lot of code actively running on that box to perform various tasks. One example is the file monitor to identify when a new WAR file is deployed to your work directory. Every piece of code routinely allocates memory that eventually gets garbage collected, thus the memory fluctuation you see.

Another piece of code that is likely consuming much of that memory is the profiler itself. For you to be able to get the metrics you get through JConsole, there needs to be an agent running on that box that is collecting (and storing in memory) the information you see.

If you want to have a better idea of what is actually being allocated by tomcat, I suggest getting your hands on a good Java Profiler that can give you more in-depth information on object allocations. I personally suggest [YourKit](https://yourkit.com/) as it is one of the most powerful profilers I have used in my many years of building software.

Now, there may be other reasons, but don't assume that just because you are not directly interacting with Tomcat that it is not doing anything.

Hope this helps, good luck!